# Pythonによる集合の計算方法について

Tags: python

現在Pythonにて以下のような集合の計算に関する処理を実装しようとしております。
もし、参考になるような実装方法やウェブサイト等ございましたら、ご教示頂きたく存じます。

```
("B" or "D") and ("A" or "B" or "C" or "D") and ("A" or "B" or "C")

= ("B" or "D") and ("A" or "B" or "C")

= "A" and "D" or "B" or "C" and "D"
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 標準形や簡単化した表現を求めたいということでしょうか？（となると集合というよりは論理っぽいですが）

Comment: はい。コメント頂いた通り、以下のような論理演算を簡略化する処理を実装したいと考えております。
(A or B) and B = B

Answer (score 5):

sympyを使うのではどうでしょう

```
>>> import sympy
>>> from sympy.logic.boolalg import to_cnf, to_dnf
>>> A, B, C, D = sympy.symbols('A,B,C,D')
>>> expr = (B | D) & (A | B | C | D) & (A | B | C)
>>> to_cnf(expr, simplify=True)
And(Or(A, B, C), Or(B, D))
>>> to_dnf(expr, simplify=True)
Or(And(A, D), And(C, D), B)
```

詳しい使い方は公式ドキュメントが参考になります http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html